# Random quote command remodel

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm fairly new to JS, I found this piece of code for a Discord bot, and I was wondering how I could make it so when someone typed !quote, the response doesn't tag the user, and require additional text to be typed along with the command from the user. Thanks

```
if (command == "quote") { 
    if (args[1] != null) message.reply(quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length).toString(16)]); // if args[1], post random answer
    else message.channel.send("!quote <your text here>"); 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question. What user are you talking about? What command?

Comment: I guess `reply` *replies* to the user, and `channel.send` sends a message to the channel?! `I'm fairly new to JS` ... Then first learn it before asking questions about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Message.reply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) sends a message in the same channel with a mention tag. If you don't want the mention tag, you have to send a message in the same channel, and you can do that with [`message.channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send)

Your code should look like this:

```
if (command == "quote") { 
  if (args[1] != null) message.channel.send(quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length).toString(16)]); // if args[1], post random answer
  else message.channel.send("!quote <your text here>"); 
}
```

If you don't want to check for any additional text, you can just get rid of the if/else check, and only leave the `message.channel.send()`:

```
if (command == "quote") message.channel.send(quote[Math.floor(Math.random() * quote.length).toString(16)]);
```

Comment: Thank you! is there anyway that when you type the command, you don't have to add any additional text? eg currently you have to do '!quote some-text-here' Sorry for being a nuisance